Add gaps in flatbuffers vector
Is it possible to have a gap or empty element in a flatbuffers vector?
I need to transfer a (variable length) list of items, where the position of the items is of relevance. However, items can be omitted, but the existing items must still be at the correct position
Assume
table Item {
  value:string;
}

table List {
  items:[Item];
}

root_type List;

void createBuffer()
{
  auto fbb = ::flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder{};
    
  auto vector = std::vector<::flatbuffers::Offset<Item>>{};
  vector.push_back(CreateItem(fbb, fbb.CreateString("Test")));
  // Adds "empty" item
  vector.push_back({});
    
  auto fVector = fbb.CreateVector(vector);
  auto list = CreateList(fbb, fVector);
  fbb.Finish(list);
}

This crashes inside the fbb.CreateVector method where the FBB vector is created.
Is there any way to add "gaps" in the vector, without modifying the Item table?

when does the empty element appear? if you know where it appears statically, what's preventing you from baking that into the schema?

create an element that represents no data and add them to the vector at empty spots. Should not matter much you're going to (de)serialize them anyway.

@haleyk No, I don't know this. And it changes

@PepijnKramer Yes, that is my workaround now. Either change Item to have a "I'm empty" field, or (as I did) make a Vector of Union, where there is a  Empty item. It's a bit cumbersome, though, so I hoped for a more direct approach

No, this is not possible. While a table field is allowed to be non present / null, all vector elements must have the specified type.
It is not possible to specify an "optional" vector element type in the schema.
Your best bet is a vector of a union type. The union would include the Item type, and every union also allows the "none" value, equivalent to null. This is a bit more work though, as you will essentially store 2 vectors, one of types, and one of values.

As commentors and @Aardappel mentioned, there is no way to add "empty" elements to a vector. I ended up to use the (newish?) feature of vector-of-unions.
However, I couldn't find a description how to use it in C++ (only a C# tutorial), so here is a sample implementation, for reference.
Basically, flatbuffers will write 2 vectors, one for the types of the elements, and one for the actual elements
table Item {
  value:string;
}

table Empty {
}

union OptionalItem {
  Item,
  Empty
}

table List {
  items:[OptionalItem];
}

root_type List;

std::vector<uint8_t> createBuffer()
{
  auto fbb = ::flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder{};

  auto itemVector = std::vector<::flatbuffers::Offset<>>{};
  auto typeVector = std::vector<OptionalItem>{};
  itemVector.push_back(CreateItem(fbb, fbb.CreateString("Test")).Union());
  typeVector.push_back(OptionalItem::Item);

  // Adds "empty" item
  itemVector.push_back(CreateEmpty(fbb).Union());
  typeVector.push_back(OptionalItem::Empty);

  auto fbbItems = fbb.CreateVector(itemVector);
  auto fbbTypes = fbb.CreateVector(typeVector);
  auto list = CreateList(fbb, fbbTypes, fbbItems);
  fbb.Finish(list);

  return std::vector<uint8_t>(fbb.GetBufferPointer(), fbb.GetBufferPointer() + fbb.GetSize());
}

void readBuffer(std::vector<uint8_t> buffer)
{
  auto list = GetList(buffer.data());
  for (int i = 0; i < list->items()->size(); ++i) {
    if (list->items_type()->Get(i) == OptionalItem::Item) {
      auto item = reinterpret_cast<const Item*>(list->items()->Get(i));
      std::cout << i << ": " << item->value()->c_str() << std::endl;
    }
    else if (list->items_type()->Get(i) == OptionalItem::Empty) {
      std::cout << i << " is empty" << std::endl;
    }
  }
}

